# How Do I Generalize the Axiom of Pairing for $n$ Sets?

Tags: set-theory

**Question:**

By induction, prove that for every sets $a_1,…,a_n$, there exists a unique set C whose elements are exactly $a_1,…a_n$.

**Attempt:**

This is true for $n=2$ by the axiom of pairing. Suppose this is true for $n=k\geq 2$, we want to show that this is true for all $n$.

For sets $a_1,…,a_k$ and set $a_{k+1}$, there exists a unique set $D$ such that $a_1,…,a_{k+1}$ are it’s elements. Hence, by induction, we conclude that for sets $a_1,…,a_n$, there exists a unique set $C$ whose elements are exactly $a_1,…,a_n$.

**My Struggle:**

My struggle here is that $D$ feels like {{$a_1,…,a_k$}, $a_{k+1}$}, instead of {$a_1,…,a_n$}. Again, I feel like there are gaps in my reasoning. How should I fix this proof?

Comment: You won't be able to prove it using **only** the axiom of pairing.

Comment: @jjagmath why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your induction step can be realised as follows:

$\{a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}\}$ is a set by induction hypothesis. $\{a_n\}$ is a set by pairing since it equals $\{a_n,a_n\}$. Then use pairing to construct the set $\{\{a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}\},\{a_n\}\}$. Then by using the union axiom we get $\bigcup\{\{a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}\},\{a_n\}\}=\{a_0,\dots,a_n\}$.

Comment: Now I see. Thanks

Comment: Vincent Batens it seems the union is the union of the elements of the sets $a_0,…,a_n$, not the union of the sets. Or, what do you think?

Comment: $\bigcup \{\{a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}\},\{a_n\}\} = \{a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}\}\cup\{a_n\}=\{a_0,\dots,a_n\}$ since union of a set is the union of its element by definition.

Comment: In other words $\bigcup\{a,b\} = a\cup b$, now substitute $a=\{a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}\}$ and $b=\{a_n\}$